# Odoo-v9 installtion

Tags: installation, odoo

I have installed odoo-9 successfully, but it need to install few more packages I think because odoo-9 is dependent on node-less.

**Problem :**

After installed odoo-9 screen will not render completely, so anyone knows the reason why this happen ?

There is no more help available for odoo-9 and it's dependent packages.

Already refereed:

[odoo 9 on Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS](http://openies.com/blog/install-openerp-odoo-9-on-ubuntu-server-14-04-lts/)

[Odoo forum](https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/help-1/question/how-can-i-install-odoo-9-88323)

Comment: Are you trying to setup for debugging purpose?

Comment: I am trying to setup odoo-9 to test it's feature before go to live.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Issue has been resolved by installing less.

**Less CSS via nodejs**

on Linux, use your distribution's package manager to install nodejs and npm.

**Important**

In **debian wheezy** and **Ubuntu 13.10 and before** you need to install nodejs manually:

```
$ wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | bash -
$ apt-get install -y nodejs
```

In later debian (>jessie) and ubuntu (>14.04) you may need to add a symlink as npm packages call node but debian calls the binary nodejs

```
$ apt-get install -y npm
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

Once npm is installed, use it to install less and less-plugin-clean-css:

```
$ sudo npm install -g less less-plugin-clean-css
```

For more help [Click here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/setup/install.html#installing-dependencies)

Answer (score 1):

by the way thats a really outdated version of node.

instead of

> wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | bash -

use

> curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -

All the other instructions are the same.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install nodejs and less for Ubuntu you need to run :-

```
sudo curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -

sudo apt install -y nodejs

sudo npm install -g less less-plugin-clean-css
```

after run your issue get resolve .

**You can get more details tutorial about odoo installation here** [odoo Apache Ubuntu](https://youtu.be/s0BD0YFonDE)

Answer (score 0):

You can chekout this also for dependency and configuration

[Documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/setup/install.html)

Comment: Thanks I was referred same.